# Debugging unexpected results from DCount

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I have an Access database with two tables:

```
DaystoCount
|ID|Day      |Day      |
|1 |28-Feb-14|07-Mar-14|
|2 |01-May-14|02-May-14|
```

and

```
DaystoExclude
|Day        |
|27-Jan-2014|
```

I also have the following query, which is mean to find and count any 'DaystoExclude' within the 'DaystoCount':

```
SELECT  Nz([End],[Start]) AS NEndDate, 
        DCount("Day","DaystoExclude","Day >= #" & [Start] & "# and Day <= #" & [NEndDate] & "#") AS ExcludedCount
FROM DaystoCount;
```

I keep getting the following results from the query:

```
|NEndDate |ExcludedCount|
|7/03/2014|0            |
|2/05/2014|1            |
```

As neither of the date ranges include 27-Jan-2014 I am expecting to the following results:

```
|NEndDate |ExcludedCount|
|7/03/2014|0            |
|2/05/2014|0            |
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to where this code is going wrong?  Or suggestions on how to debug this?

Comment: Have you tried casting [Start] and [End] in your DCount criteria to mm/dd/yyyy format (you can use the Format function)?  Sometimes Access can act funny when not using this format.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your `Dcount` condition to:

```
"[Day] >= DateSerial(year(" & [start] & "), month(" & [start] & "), day(" & [start] & ")) or [Day] <= DateSerial(year(" & [nEndDate] & "), month(" & [nEndDate] & "), day(" & [nEndDate] & "))"
```

This will ensure that date format will not affect condition on `[day]` field.

Comment: thanks but unfortunately that doesn't help.  If I change the day to exclude to 02-May-14 I receive 0 days excluded.

Comment: @Hammer, I've changed my answer. Reading with more attenction, the problem seems to be the AND in condition. You need an OR. Anyway, I suggest you to use DateSerial too.